# NET-SNMP: custom disman monitor not sending trap

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I configured in the snmpd.conf file the "extend" function to monitor a custom script.

```
extend shelltest /bin/sh /tmp/snmptest.sh
```

Then I checked the MIB for this if this "extend" function is working or not. I am able to see all Mibs for this.

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2
```

If the output of my custom script returns a failed state then the following OID returns other valued then 0.

```
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendResult."shelltest" = INTEGER: 3
```

The disman monitors looks like this:

```
monitor -r 30 -u internal -o ErrorMsg "False" nsExtendResult."shelltest" != 0
```

So from my point of view if the nsExtendResult."shelltest" return other values then 0 a trap should be triggered.

I tried several options for the monitor function but it was never working. The default monitors for example disk monitor or file monitors are working well.

Comment: We probably don't have enough information to diagnose this remotely. Is there anything interesting in log files? Have you confirmed (via packet capture) that the trap is never dispatched?